# Why would anyone use execute() function in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I know that execute() is a synchronous function which means Until you are able to use it should execute it in other threads.

But I want to understand why would I use execute function even though enqueue function exists that does this work (execute on other thread) itself.

what are cases that should use execute function in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, you are already on a background thread, supplied by something else:

- `JobIntentService`
- `WorkManager`
- Kotlin coroutines
- RxJava
- Etc.

In those cases, you may not need OkHttp or Retrofit to use yet another background thread and can use `execute()` for simpler code.

Comment: it is just to make code simpler??
there is no difference between `execute()` and `enqueue()` functions other that?

Comment: @AmrJyniat: `enqueue()` does the work on a background thread. `execute()` does the work on the current thread. If you already are on a background thread, usually you do not need `enqueue()`.